# How to use different plot that is generated in Shiny Module server function in the UI ? (See detail)

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app that takes a module to do the multiple graph and I want to display these graph in multiple different places in the main Shiny UI. For example the below code has one moduleserver function that generate plot1 and plot2 which is also mention in the module ui part. But I dont know how I will call plot1 and plot2 separately.

- This is module code:

```
mod_dt_UI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    uiOutput(ns("plot1")),
    uiOutput(ns("plot2")),
    uiOutput(ns("plot3"))
  )
}

mod_dt_Server <- function(id, dsin) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {

      output$plot1<- renderPlotly({
            Some graph code. 
       })
      output$plot2<- renderPlotly({
            Some graph code. 
       })
      output$plot3<- renderPlotly({
            Some graph code. 
       })
     }
   )
}
```

- This is the main App UI and server

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  mod_dt_UI("plot1")  #These plot will be displayed in different pages in the SHiny app. 
  mod_dt_UI("plot2") #These plot will be displayed in different pages in the SHiny app. 
  mod_dt_UI("plot3")  #These plot will be displayed in different pages in the SHiny app. 
)

# Define the server function
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Call the module and assign its output to the placeholder
    mod_dt_Server(id="plot1", dsin=df)
}
```

Tried to access using `mod_dt_UI("plot1")` but not able to get what I want. All plots together.

Comment: Return the required plots from the module server function.  Assign the return value to an object in app's main server function and then reference them where you need.  Without working code, that's likely to be all we can tell you.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70265644/best-practices-for-returning-a-server-side-generated-value-from-a-shiny-module) for an example of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Specify a unique `ID` for each plot with the id argument of `renderPlotly`
2. In the `mod_dt_UI` function change `uiOutput` to `plotOutput`, this will create a placeholder for each plot with the same `ID` from `renderPlotly`.

Here is an example with the `mtcars` dataset:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

# Module UI function
mod_dt_UI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    plotlyOutput(ns("plot1")),
    plotlyOutput(ns("plot2")),
    plotlyOutput(ns("plot3"))
  )
}

# Module server function
mod_dt_Server <- function(id, dsin) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      
      output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({
        # Plot 1
        dsin %>%
          group_by(am) %>%
          summarise(mean_mpg = mean(mpg)) %>%
          plot_ly(x = ~am, y = ~mean_mpg, type = "bar")
      })
      
      output$plot2 <- renderPlotly({
        # Plot 2
        dsin %>%
          group_by(am) %>%
          summarise(mean_hp = mean(hp)) %>%
          plot_ly(x = ~am, y = ~mean_hp, type = "bar")
      })
      
      output$plot3 <- renderPlotly({
        # Plot 3
        dsin %>%
          group_by(am) %>%
          summarise(mean_mpg = mean(mpg), mean_hp = mean(hp)) %>%
          plot_ly(x = ~am, y = ~mean_mpg, type = "bar", name = "Mean MPG") 
      })
      
    }
  )
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  mod_dt_UI("plot1"),
  mod_dt_UI("plot2"),
  mod_dt_UI("plot3")
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  mod_dt_Server(id = "plot1", dsin = mtcars)
  mod_dt_Server(id = "plot2", dsin = mtcars)
  mod_dt_Server(id = "plot3", dsin = mtcars)
}

# Run the app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

example output:
[image]